# Quicker, non-secure, replacement needed for MD5/SHA1 hash functions

Tags: hash, md5, sha1, checksum

I need a non-crypto-secure hash function which produces at least 16 bytes of output.

I'm currently using MD5, but it's too slow, by a factor of around 5 times.

Adler32, CRC32, etc. do not produce the required amount of output.

Is there a way of turning checksums into hash functions, producing the required 16 bytes+ of output?

Comment: More bytes of output don't mean collisions are less likely, the quality of the hash function is at least as important. Why do you want 16 bytes outputs? Would just padding a shorter output (e.g. with zeros) suffice?

Comment: I could pad with *some* zeros, but a 32bit (best case - one in four billion) chance of collision is too close for comfort.  CRC-64 could be a solution, if it really has the collision resistance that its output size map implies.

Comment: As I said before, collision resistance is at best only partially related to output size, so don't read too much into it. What do you need those for anyway?

Comment: @delnan hashing sparse terabyte files - a comment on a related question has yielded a great solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15007629/optimise-updating-md5-sha1-with-streams-of-zeros#comment-21094060

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I initially used 4 different 32 bit checksums and concatenated their output to make 16 bytes.

I then solved the problem properly: [Optimise updating MD5/SHA1 with streams of zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15007629/optimise-updating-md5-sha1-with-streams-of-zeros#comment-21094060)